# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener firing more than once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, tabs

I am making a chrome extension, and in my background scripts I have an `addListener`, but it is firing more than once even though it is an `onUpdated.addListener`. I added an if statement to check for when `changeInfo.status == 'complete'`, but it is STILL firing multiple times. I know Google Chrome had a bug that had to do with this, but that was years ago. Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Here is my background.js:

```
// Get the behavior of the plugin; the default is set to "onClick", the other option is "alwaysOn"
chrome.storage.sync.get({
extensionBehavior: 'onClick'
}, function(items) {
    if(items.extensionBehavior == 'onClick'){
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
            // When the extension icon is clicked, send a message to the content script
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"message": tabs[0].url}, function(response){});
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"auto"});
        chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
                if (tab.status == 'complete') {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": tab.url}, function(response){});
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.2.1",
"description": *redacted for privacy reasons*,
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "js": ["content_script.js", "jquery-2.2.4.js"]
  }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "blue-logo.png"
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
]
}
```

If you're wondering why I have an `onUpdated` inside of my `onCreated`, it's because the onCreated wasn't working alone, and I also need it to fire when tabs that have previously been created are also updated (as in, I create a tab, go to a URL, and then go to another URL with that tab). I was checking for `changeInfo.status` at first, but when that wasn't working I changed it to `tab.status`, are these not the same variable? Both seem to give the same behavior (firing when they aren't supposed to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a new listener to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` every time a tab is created:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        ...
```

which means if you create three tabs, your `unUpdated` listener will be called three times any time one tab is updated. The `tab` parameter for the `onCreated` event is also being ignored because the `onUpdated` callback takes a parameter of the same name.

If you need to listen to both events, you should add each listener separately:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    ...
});
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Question, if I create a new tab, then the listener will fire because of `onCreated`, but won't it also fire for `onUpdated` once the newly created tab is finished loading? @mgiuffrida

EDIT: Nevermind! It works like a charm, thank you!